# Can't use Python 3.8 version interpreter in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, ide, interpreter, python-3.8

I've tried to upgrade Python version to 3.8 and when I want to add the interpreter in PyCharm I get the following:

[image]

I have no idea as to why this happens. When I type `python -V` in the command prompt I get Python 3.8.3.

EDIT: Python version actually is updated but PyCharm still marks the code as if the version is 3.

Comment: You already have Python 3.8.3, your interpreter is just called "Python 3.7" but looking at the path everything seems ok

Comment: You might need to manually add it. Expand that Python Interpreter list, then Show All..., then click the "+", followed by System Interpreter.

Comment: Yeah I did manually add this path and then I got this interpreter. @Thomas As for the first comment, I tried walrus operator, for example, to see if Python 3.8 version works but it didn't recognize it

Comment: Even that you called it "Python 3.7", from the path looks like its python 3.8.
Also I will suggest to add new virtualenv using python3.8.

Comment: What is a PyCharm version? It could be the one that was released before python 3.8 support has been implemented in pycharm.